# Como removo um arquivo do git com espaçamento nas palavras?

Tags: git, github

Bom, eu consegui remover um arquivo sem espaçamento `xd.txt` mas quando eu criei o meu primeiro arquivo `Novo Documento de Texto.txt` ele veio com espaço e por isso o comando não ta dando certo
O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: tentou colocar entre aspas "novo documento de texto.txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei de encontrar a solução caso alguem esteja com a mesma duvida,
onde tiver espaço vcs devem colocar uma `\` parecido com o linux

ex: `Novo\ Documento\ de\ Texto.txt`

Comment: fala do comando git rm? A pergunta não esta bem clara e a resposta também me deixou em duvida.

Comment: Sim kk eu instalei agora, to perdido, acho que por isso minha pergunta não ficou clara mas muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: A sua pergunta não ficou clara porque não informou o comando que usou, sempre que for formular uma pergunta mostre o que fez, isso ajuda entender aonde é o problema. ;) Boa sorte

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente tenha que colocar entre aspas, assim: `"Novo Documento de Texto.txt"`

Supondo que esteja falando do `rm`, deve ficar assim:

```
git rm "Novo Documento de Texto.txt"
git commit -m "arquivo removido"
```